# Rails group and sum array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A production has_many :production_lines,
production_line   belongs_to :item,
item has_one :recipe,
recipe has_many :recipe_lines,
recipe_line belongs_to :item,

`production_line` and `recipe line` have attribute `quantity`. I need to group recipe_lines for a production by item, with quantity that equals to production_line.quantity * recipe_line.quantity

```
  def item_quantities
        array = production_lines.map do |p|
          p.item.recipe.recipe_lines.map do |r|
            {
              item_id: r.item_id,
              item_name: r.item.name,
              quantity: r.quantity * p.quantity
            }
          end
        end
        array.flatten(1).group_by { |p| p[:item_id] }
             .transform_values { |vals| vals.sum { |val| val[:quantity] } }
          end
```

This returns:

```
item_quantities = {
1: 10,
2: 5
}
```

where key is item_id and value is quantity. Values are correct.

However I would like to return:

```
item_quantities = [
{
id: 1,
name: "Tomato",
quantity: 10,
},
{
id: 2, 
name: "Carrot",
quantity: 5
}
]
```

How should I change my solution to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your nested `map` followed by `flatten(1)` can be simplified by making the first `map` into [`flat_map`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map). If you do this you could remove the `flatten(1)`.

From this point your code is most of the way there, but you could make the following changes to get the desired output:

1. you can group by multiple attributes, name and id. In another language you might use a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) for this. Ruby doesn't have tuples, so we can just use a len-2 array:

   ```
   .group_by { |p| [p[:item_id], p[:item_name]] }
   .transform_values { |vals| vals.sum { |val| val[:quantity] } }
   ```
2. At this point you have a hash mapping [id,name] tuple to quantity:

   ```
   { [1,"foo"] => 123, [2, "bar"] => 456 }
   ```

   and you can coerce this to the desired data type using [`reduce`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/reduce) (or [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object), if you prefer):

   ```
   .reduce([]) do |memo, ((id, name), quantity)|
     memo << {
       id: id,
       name: name,
       quantity: quantity
     }
   end
   ```

The wierd looking `((id, name), quantity)` is a kind of destructuring. See https://jsarbada.wordpress.com/2019/02/05/destructuring-with-ruby/ specifically the sections on "Destructuring Block Arguments" and "Destructuring Hashes".

Comment: I think there is an error in the point 1 where you do he group_by. A } missing I guess.

Comment: My bad, I had an extra `{` actually

Comment: Ok so in the group_by, changing p[:item_id] to [p.item_id] returns undefined method `item_id' for #<Hash....

Comment: Before grouping, I have an array of objects. Each object looks like { "item_id": "aadc79b9-ff50-4012-b2cb-0deee88138a9", "item_name": "Pumpkins", "quantity": "600.0" }

Comment: Yeah my bad @Catmal it was another error on my part, updated answer it should be `[p[:item_id], p[:item_name]]`